# Working with Python & Txt file and put data in excel or access data base

Tags: python, excel, ms-access

I am brand new to programming and I am trying to learn but there is something I need to figure out a way before I have the time vested in learning everything.  I am really hoping I could get some help.

I have txt files that are saved in a particular folder multiple times a day.  This data I am wanting to put in an Access Database and/or an excel file, multiple times a day.  Every 3 hours or so.

Depending on what folder the txt file is taken from, I need to add a Machine number, for example, I would need the header to be named Line & the machines numbers go from 1 to 19 and a Brown.

Txt File
https://gpkhk-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/br243_app365pro_site/ERPdfMBgtFVGndV9-AZFaZIBjYntuKKF3Y2s96xMc4aMwQ?e=9MDSol

Excel example
https://gpkhk-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/br243_app365pro_site/EU34Nt3jAI9Bhr1WxUT1AxIBaS5E-0bIcrhYUWyz45LneQ?e=eVPWBE

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general. About executing every 3 hours, you can:

- Do it from Access (I'll talk about Access, as it's a better tool for the kind of job you plan), using a timer. This has the disadvantage that you have to keep the Access application open at all times, and if it hangs, it's difficult to know. To do it this way, simply create a form that logs activity, and use the Form.TimerInterval property.
- Do it from Windows, using the Task Scheduler and launching your Access database. Then, in the Access database use the AutoExec special macro and execute some VBA function. I would recommend doing it that way in your case.

About the parsing of the text file, you'll have to open the file in you function, read every line, and insert the data. As I have said, your question is too broad. You should advance all you can and then post (or more likely just browse) your questions.